# Ruby on Rails array delete_if block, string is "missing translation: no key" inside but fine outside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My problem is that the `print t` inside the `delete_if` block prints *'translation missing: en.no key'*

This is strange. The error message in the browser shows me my pages parameters.
Here is what is says for `tutor_id`:

```
"tutor_id"=>["1", "2"].
```

I also tried the following inside the block to make sure it was right, and it did indeed return String.

```
print t.class  # => returns 'String'
```

Also making a call to the following inside the block yields an error

```
Integer(t) # => yields error: invalid value for Integer(): "translation missing: en.no key"
```

Likewise, a call to `.to_i` is not helpful. It always returns `0`. Note: this is the behavior o any non-numerical string such as `'hello'.to_s`

```
print t.to_i  # always prints '0'
```

The following is the troublesome code:

```
#get an array of all tutors' IDs
tutorIds = params[:tutor_id]

tutorIds.delete_if { [t] 
    print t
    Schedule.exists?(["tutor_id = ?", Integer(t)])
}
```

**Update** I left out a bit of information so if the `delete_if` block is

```
tutorIds.delete_if { [t] 
    print t
    Schedule.exists?(["tutor_id = ?", t ])
}
```

The error I get is:

> PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "translation missing: en.no key" LINE 1: ...ECT 1 AS one FROM "schedules" WHERE (tutor_id = 'translati... ^ : SELECT 1 AS one FROM "schedules" WHERE (tutor_id = 'translation missing: en.no key') LIMIT 1

Comment: Use single equals sign `=` instead of double.  `Schedule.exists?(["tutor_id = ?", Integer(t) ])`

Comment: Noted, fixed. Still doesn't address the problem. Integer(t) also yields an error: invalid value for Integer(t): "translation missing: en.no key"

Comment: I don't think casting to integer is necessary here but try `t.to_i` instead of `Integer(t)`.

Comment: calling .to_i returns 0 which is the same as a non-numeric string usually returns ,e.g: 'hello'.to_i returns 0

Comment: Dont understand why my question was voted down. Although a simple mistake, it was well-written and very descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it was right under my nose. Such a simple mistake. Notice the `[]` -> `||`

```
tutorIds.delete_if { [t] 
print t
Schedule.exists?(["tutor_id = ?", t ])}
```

Should have been

```
tutorIds.delete_if { |t| 
print t
Schedule.exists?(["tutor_id = ?", t ])}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
Schedule.where("tutor_id = ?", t.to_i).exists?
```

instead?

Comment: This doesn't help. t.to_i returns 0 just like any non-numeric string would

Comment: Why is it non-numeric?  I thought tutor_ids = ['1', '2']

Comment: I am describing the behavior. It acts as if it were operating on a non-numeric string.

Comment: What happens if you log tudorIds immediately before the 'delete_if' statement?